# Ember-cli ProxyPass

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, proxypass

I'm developing an app using ember-cli and it need to send http request to a server using a ProxyPass.

My server looks like this : subdomain.domain.com/api/clients/users and Ember-cli create by default http://localhost:4200/

I tried to do this in my http.conf :

```
ProxyPass /api/clients http://subdomain.domain.com/api/clients
```

This is working fine for http://localhost/api/clients, but I don't know how to make it works with a non standard port such as 4200.

I also try to create a virtualHost but it's the same :

```
<VirtualHost *:4200>
    ProxyPass /api/clients http://subdomain.domain.com/api/clients
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I do that ?

[EDIT]:
I set my RESTAdapter like this :

```
var ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api/clients'
});
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for here. When you deploy your ember app to production, it will be on Port 80 typically (you don't use ember-cli to serve the site in production), and you'll use ProxyPass there to direct your API from whatever other port to Port 80. Are you asking how to test against your API during development? You don't need apache if so.

Comment: I have the ember app in my localhost, not deploy on the server, the proxypass is just for my localhost apache not for the server.
I need to set it up so from my localhost so I will be able to send request to the server. Sorry if I am unclear..

Because if I set a host and a namespace in my app it will throw me this :` o 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During development, you should use an http-proxy generator to create a path to your API. `ember help generate` lists the syntax:

```
http-proxy <local-path> <remote-url>
  Generates a relative proxy to another server.
```

This generates a proxy that only exists during development (in `/server/proxies/`), and is not compiled in a production build. This is likely what you're looking for, based on what you've provided above:

```
ember generate http-proxy api http://subdomain.domain.com
```

Ember uses [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to create the proxy, so you can customize it more using that documentation if necessary.

Comment: It seems that this is exactly what I am looking for. I did "ember generate http-proxy api http://subdomain.domain.com/api" but it try to reach  http://localhost:4200/api/clients/users for the GET instead of http://subdomain.domain.com/api/clients/users. Do I need to set something else ?

Comment: It *should* hit the API at localhost, but the call should be proxied to your other site afterwards if it's working correctly. Perhaps it should have been /api instead of api - Go to `/server/proxies/api.js` and check the proxyPath variable at the top. If it reads `proxyPath = 'api'`, try changing it to `'/api'` and see if it fixes it. You should be able to hit your API at http://localhost:4200/api/clients/users manually and see the same response as if you hit your subdomain path.

Comment: It seems that ember generate put automatically the / if we don't set one which in anycase would be the correct proxyPath in api.js. Even trying to hit the url manually but it's 404. I even tried to run ember server --proxy http://subdomain.domain.com/api/ but it's the same thing

Comment: Try removing the /api from your subdomain. `ember generate http-proxy api http://subdomain.domain.com` (or change the target in `api.js`). I tried here with `ember generate http-proxy api http://google.com` and hitting http://localhost:4200/api took me to http://google.com/api (if I had google.com/api, it redirected to google.com/api/api instead). Also, you can take a look at the documentation for the http-proxy server itself here: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Comment: I did remove the /api from my domain, but still can't access it, either with the request and manually.. I don't really understand what's wrong here, the proxypass is working on my localhost, so I guess there is nothing to do on the server side because it should works. I put my RESTAdapter I extended in the topic to be sure that is correct.

Comment: Ok I manage to make it works, it is a little bit weird but working. I set a `ProxyPass` for my localhost to proxy to my server and then I set `ember generate http-proxy api http://127.0.0.1` . The result is that it will proxy on my localhost and it is working. I have no idea why this is not working directly from the proxy to the server. Thank you for your help !